# How can I insert a newline in a localized value for a String in a .wxl file?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm  using a .wxl file to customize the text in the various dialogs in WixUI_FeatureTree.  How can I insert a newline?

This doesn't work:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="WelcomeDlgTitle">{\WixUI_Font_Bigger}Welcome to the Setup Wizard for\r\n[ProductName]</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

If I try that, I get "\r\n" in the text in the dialog.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't have experience of this particular use but you might be able to use entities, e.g.

```
First Line&#13;&#10;Second Line
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me on WIX 3.5:

```
First Line&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Second Line
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18446742/2486445