# WiX Simple Line Break?

Tags: string, wix

Using 3.5 and I just want a newline character in my Text Element:

```
<Dialog><Control><Text>
    &#13;&#10;The [Wizard] will install [ProductName]
    &#13;&#10;on your computer.
    &#13;&#10;Click Next to continue or Cancel to exit the [Wizard].
</Text></Control>....
```

That does not seem to insert a new line character. How can I get a linebreak in there?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question][1]. (Haven't tried this on my own.)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780363/how-can-i-insert-a-newline-in-a-localized-value-for-a-string-in-a-wxl-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately Windows Installer doesn’t support line breaks in static text controls. During installation the text is automatically formatted based on control and font sizes.

However, if you really want a line break, simply use another static text control for the next line.

Answer (score 3):

The [official answer from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding line breaks in Text controls reads as follows:

> The recommended method for displaying text with specified line breaks is to use multiple one-line text controls located below each other. The character sequences \n, \r\n, or \n\r in the text field for the control are not displayed as a line break. These character sequences are literally displayed by the control.

Answer (score 3):

Use CDATA as stumbled upon in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124094/insert-crlf-in-a-wix-text-control) question:

```
<Control><Text>
<![CDATA[
This is my text.
With a return line
]]>
</Text></Control>
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on Adam's answer you can also format your text into a WixLocalization entry.
Example:

```
 <WixLocalization xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization" Culture="en-US">
    <String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription">
        This is a custom welcome message. 
        Click Next to continue or 
        Cancel to exit.</String>
  </WixLocalization>
```

And use it in your control like this:

```
<Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="50" Y="20" Width="200" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgDescription)"/>
```

Comment: This worked for me when the CDATA approach did not. Thank you.