# Insert crlf in a Wix Text Control

Tags: installation, wix

This could be a silly or stupid question, but how do I enter a carriage return (crlf) in the text of a Wix Text Control?

I tried:

```
<Control Type="Text">
    <Text>Text goes here</Text>
    <Text>Another text goes here</Text>
</Control>
```

But of course wix says that I cannot have more than one Text element inside a control tag.

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure is something easy to do but my google foo is failing right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was easier than expected and was in front of me all this time... Using CDATA is the way to do it...

So, doing a return car in a text control is just matter of enclosing the text in CDATA, for example:

```
<Control Type="Text">
<Text><![CDATA[
This is my text.
With a return line
]]>
</Text>
</Control>
```

Looks like there could be more ways to do it, but I found that one the simpler.

Comment: It's work! Thanks! Having 2 additional controls - ugly solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Windows Installer does not support line breaks in static text controls. During installation the text is automatically formatted based on control and font sizes.

However, if you really want a line break, simply use another static text control for the next line.

Comment: I don't like this method, was my first approach and yes, it works, but the problem is that you would end with another text control for something that should be located in the same text control, it works, yes, but I don't find it very 'declarative' =(